# Deleting row on trigger before insert, with on duplicate update

Tags: mysql, triggers

#### Situation

I am saving modifications done on users' profiles (for a logging purpose).

I am using this query to insert/update in a :

```
INSERT INTO infos_update (username, date_modif, column_name, old_value, new_value)
  VALUES ('johnsmith', CURDATE(), 'department', 'Management', 'IT/IS')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new_value='IT/IS, date_modif=CURDATE()
```

The primary key is composed of `date_modif, username, column_name`, where date is a date and not a datetime.

#### Goal

I want to use a trigger to avoid logging values that did not changed (where old_value and new_value are equals)

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_infos_update 
BEFORE INSERT ON infos_update FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NEW.old_value = NEW.new_value THEN
  DELETE FROM infos_update 
    WHERE infos_update.username= NEW.username
    AND infos_update.date_modif = NEW.date_modif
    AND infos_update.column_name = NEW.column_name;
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Values are the same';
END IF;
END\\`
```

It prevents duplicates on initial insert, but when the row is already inserted, `on duplicate key update` can still update rows with duplicate old and new values; even when simply deleting the row before the update with that trigger

Comment: You cannot delete a row in the same table the trigger is on. So while your trigger seems to do what you want (it raises an exception), it is due to the `delete`, not the `signal`. You can do the same in an update trigger (the signal part). Instead of correcting data after the fact, have you considered simply not to insert it in the first place (e.g. add an `if` (in e.g. php) before you run the `insert`). Generally: why do you want to log changes on the same day differently than doing it on 2 days (e.g. 23:59 and 0:01)? Just log everything, and filter it when you look at it.